# Apply function in a matrix gives binary operator error

Tags: r

I have the following matrix called `al_freq`:

```
structure(c(0.3204, 0.3266, 0.3645, 0.1615, 0.2884, 
0.3042, 0.4437, 0.3896,0.4264, 0.2308, 0.2997, 
0.3148, 0.1408, 0.1036, 0.076, 0.0923, 0.0604, 
0.0776, 0.1373, 0.0878, 0.0686, 0.0957, 0.0579, 
0.0767, 0.3134, 0.3176, 0.3612, 0.1248, 0.2237, 
0.0847, 0.1408, 0.1014, 0.0686, 0.0906, 0.0596, 0.075), 
.Dim = c(6L, 6L), .Dimnames = list(c("ES1-5", "ES6-13", 
"ES14-26", "ES27-38", "SA1-13", "SA14-25"), 
c("1A-1145442", "1A-1158042", "1A-1158055", 
"1A-1229616", "1A-1236254", "1A-1238114")))
```

It looks this way :

```
       1A-1145442 1A-1158042 1A-1158055 1A-1229616 1A-1236254 1A-1238114
ES1-5       0.3204     0.4437     0.1408     0.1373     0.3134     0.1408
ES6-13      0.3266     0.3896     0.1036     0.0878     0.3176     0.1014
ES14-26     0.3645     0.4264     0.0760     0.0686     0.3612     0.0686
ES27-38     0.1615     0.2308     0.0923     0.0957     0.1248     0.0906
SA1-13      0.2884     0.2997     0.0604     0.0579     0.2237     0.0596
SA14-25     0.3042     0.3148     0.0776     0.0767     0.0847     0.0750
```

When I use the `apply` function : `apply(al_freq[1:6,1:6], 2,function(x) x-mean)`

I get this error :

> Error in x - mean: non-numeric argument to binary operator

I don't understand why this is the case as apply loops through every element of the matrix which is numeric obviously. Where am I wrong here?

Comment: perhaps `apply(al_freq[1:6,1:6], 2,function(x) x - mean(x) )` ?  you have to tell `mean()` where to take the mean of...

Comment: Alternative: `apply(al_freq, 2, scale, scale = FALSE)`.

Comment: `scale(al_freq, scale = FALSE)`

Comment: Or this : `sweep(al_freq, 2, colMeans(al_freq))`